# How to call REST APIs from Django?

Tags: python, django, rest

Not new to programming, but new to Django

**Where do I place the code in my Django project that calls an external REST API?**

In the simplest example: I have a form where the user enters their ZIP code and presses a "Check" button which tells if the customer's address can be serviced by the lawn care company.

Upon getting a response, I have to the JSON to determine if it's serviceable, and what kind of services, etc.

So I need to be able to send, and read responses.

Where do I do this?

There is no database involved, so I presume I don't use a model.

I don't think the "View" is a good spot

Where?!

Thanks!

Comment: Unless it's going to take ages for the API to respond - then no harm putting it in the view as that's the natural trigger for it and you want to know the result of the api call before you can return the result of the view anyway... eg: User loads page, user enters zip and clicks check, as part of the validation of the form, you take into account the result of the api, then you know whether the form submission should be considered successful or not...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the reply. That sounds like a good idea for a small call. However, what if I want to write a wrapper over the REST API? Where would I put that "module" or "class" that wraps it?

Comment: Wherever you want really... maybe have it as a separate app? There's no one right way to structure a project...

Comment: @JonClements Interesting... So if I have my "address checker" as an entirely separate app, it still begs the question: where, in that separate app, would I put that code that wraps the API? What I wanted to do was create a wrapper class for it, but I just don't know where to put it.  Is there sort of a standard to go off?

Comment: Just figured it's a common issue that perhaps they have a proper way. Otherwise, I suppose I could just create a class within the views.py file itself?

Comment: or just create a new file called `address_checker.py` and put your stuff in there and import what you need from it for use in the view...

Comment: @JonClements OK thanks. I guess it was more so a question of structure of where I put this AddressChecker class, but I suppose there is no right / wrong way. I presume I would put in the /views directory? Or is there some other directory for this sort of thing?

Comment: Maybe create a separate module called Utils within your app, add all functions that call 3rd party APIs there. You could also add other helper methods there that could be used throughout your project.

Comment: @VarunRathore Thanks. I've read something similar as well. Where would be the appropriate directory to store that utils / helper file?